# Ember simple auth: how to redirect back to the last visiting route after authentication?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

If user was trying to visit a `/protected-route`, then using `ember-simple-auth` after user authentication finished on `/login` route, how to redirect user back to the `/protected-route`?

There is configuration to define the route after authentication but how to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mixin the `ApplicationRouteMixin` into the application route and the user will transition to `protected route` after login.

For more info see `ApplicationRouteMixin` docs at http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/ApplicationRouteMixin.html and the `sessionAuthenticated` method

Comment: You point me to the right direction. I had that maxin on application route but I was doing a transition forcefully based on some other condition which seemed disabling this build-in behavior. Thanks!